# What does "anti-midian" mean for Hellsing's Victoria Seras' signature weapon Harkonnen?

Tags: weapon, anime, hellsing-anime

> Hellsing ARMS Anti-Midian Cannon 'Harkonnen'.

What does "Anti-Midian" mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A long time ago there was a movie called "Nightbreed" directed by Clive Barker. Clive Barker is the guy who made the "Hellraiser" series. This was one of his earlier works and oddly enough had a young David Cronenberg of "The Fly" fame play as the antagonist. In the movie "Nightbreed" monsters are trying to make an utopian city for their kind away from humans called "Midian". In the movie, the human protagonist Boone must choose between becoming a monster or keeping his humanity for the love of a human girl. So it ties in with the overall Hellsing motif of humanity.

But in general "anti-midian" probably refers to any creatures that are against humanity, and Hellsing's objective to stop monsters from populating the Earth. Bam! Overanalysis of a mindless action anime!

Bonus Info! In the manga Hellsing when the Nazi Vampires surround Integra in the burning visages of London, one of them tells Integra "Throw in the towel human, there is no place in this city left for you to run and hide. You're no longer in London, this is now "Midian" the city of death."

Comment: Downvote because the movie is called "Nightbreed".

Comment: Random trivia: "Nightbreed" is based on Clive Barker's own novella "Cabal".

Comment: Another random trivia: The novel Cabal was renamed to "Night breed" (with space) in some translations.

Answer (score 5):

As I remember from the series, the vampires were referred to as *midians*, as you can also check [here](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.com/definitions/Midian?cx=partner-pub-0939450753529744%3av0qd01-tdlq&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&q=Midian&sa=Search#906). So *anti-midian* would be *anti-vampire*

Why did they choose it, I don't know and I don't seem to be [the only one](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070717140402AAxBeD8).

Answer (score 3):

In hellsing midian is used as a term to describe non-human, dangerous enteties such as vampires, werewolfes (and possibly anything else that can exist in the hellsing universe). anti-midian could be understood as anti-monster weapon

Answer (score 1):

If we are to talk about the term `midian`, it's very likely it's inspired by the Bible. According to it, the [Midianites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midian) were an Arabic tribe that worshiped multiple deities, hence being considered sinners. They had oppressed Israel and because of that, God ordered war on them.

[From what I read](http://christianthinktank.com/midian.html), they were brutally slaughtered by Moses:

> In Numbers 31:15-18, after his soldiers had killed all of the men
>   among the Midianites, Moses ordered his army officers to kill all of
>   the male children, kill all of the nonvirgin females but to save alive
>   all of the virgin girls for his troops.

I'm assuming these atrocities were taken into consideration by the mangaka. In the anime series, Alucarad is revealed to be in fact

> Judas

Based on the same reasoning and with the rather similar backgrounds, he might have considered the midians as a source of inspiration for the vampires in the series.